# How to create JavaScript projects in Netbeans 7?

Tags: javascript, netbeans, ide

I have the basic Java version of NetBeans installed, but I want to be able to create JavaScript/HTML projects with auto-completion and other IDE-supported functionality. I can't seem to find out what I need to install to do this. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

There is no dedicated Javascript project type in Netbeans 7. There are still various possibilities to work on HTML/JS files:

1. Add a JS/HTML file to any of the available projects, e.g. a PHP project.
2. Open the JS/HTML file directly without having a project by using
   File/Open.
3. [Define own project type](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-projecttype.html). This is likely not so easy.

In any case you will be able to edit the file and utilize the IDE language features like autocompletion, etc. But you will not be able to run/debug the JS file. For debugging you will need to use the debuggers integrated with the browsers (*Developer Tools* in IE, Chrome; *Firebug* in Firefox, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You install the PHP plugin from the Plugin directory. This isn't explained anywhere that I can see, I just had to guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the php bundle for netbeans [here](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html).You can also create xml,json,css,php pages with it.